# Our mobile website does not scrolling vertically

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, sitefinity

Having searched the net for the last 3 hrs I still can not solve why this site can't scroll on a mobile device...aaargh

http://basfdev.cooee.co.nz

Cheers

Comment: what mobile browser are you using?

Comment: Actually all. Both on Android and iPhone. I discovered it may be a script as when I disable jquery it then scrolls fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a script called AddThis. Got rid of it and now all is fine